The spring initializr CLI gives the error message spring groupid is not a recognized option
On the simplest use case
spring init --groupId com.example hi

the Spring initialzr CLI gives the error message
groupId is not a recognized option

The SpringBoot release is 3.3.0

It works with the group parameter as in:
spring init --group com.example hi

This looks inconsistent with the documentation given by the spring init --list command:
Parameters
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Id          | Description                              | Default value                |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| artifactId  | project coordinates (infer archive name) | demo                         |
| bootVersion | spring boot version                      | 3.3.0                        |
| description | project description                      | Demo project for Spring Boot |
| groupId     | project coordinates                      | com.example                  |
| javaVersion | language level                           | 17                           |
| language    | programming language                     | java                         |
| name        | project name (infer application name)    | demo                         |
| packageName | root package                             | com.example.demo             |
| packaging   | project packaging                        | jar                          |
| type        | project type                             | gradle-project               |
| version     | project version                          | 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------+

As this above command lists a groupId parameter.
The same thing occurs with the artifactId parameter, which becomes artifact on the CLI.
